# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message with and embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I can't figure out the issue, it always comes up with cannot send an empty message

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'actualhelp',
    description: "here is some ACTUAL help",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#304281')
        .setTitle('Help')
        .setURL('URL')
        .setDescription('Here is some basic help')
        .addFields(
            {name: '4/102', value: 'Base Set Charizard'},
            {name: 'cool', value: 'You will become cool with the Looking Epic role'},
            {name: 'ugly', value: 'Thats not nice, you are now not cool and have your Looking Epic role removed if you already had it'},
            {name: 'help', value: 'get fooled kiddo, I aint helping you'},
            {name: 'kick', value: 'checks to see if you can kick people'},
            {name: 'ping', value: 'play some ping pong with me'}
        )
        .setImage('Image url');

        message.channel.send({newEmbed});
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are sending the embed currently is identical to this:

```js
message.channel.send({newEmbed: newEmbed})
```

However this is not a valid property to set. Instead, you can do `embed: newEmbed`

```js
message.channel.send({
  embed: newEmbed
})
```

or on v13, `embeds: [newEmbed]`

```js
message.channel.send({
  embeds: [newEmbed]
})
```